# Optimised Function to copy columns of selected data by a variable amount (up/down)

Tags: performance, emeditor

Is it possible to create a javascript function that can be used in macros, that can move data by an amount when moving columns of data by variable rows. For example, by passing a parameter (iRow?) to something like setcolumn and it would insert the data either above (-1 to lose the first value and then insert which is like moving the column data up one line up for example) or +2 (to blank the first 2 rows column data and then paste the rest of the data, which is like moving it down 2 columns?

Ideally optimised for speed when working on very large amounts of data (millions of rows). Couple of examples. Col1 is source data, Col2 is copying that column and moving up by one row (-1). Col3 is copying that initial col and moving down by two (+2):

| Data | Data-1 | Data+2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | 00000002 |  |
| 00000002 | 00000003 |  |
| 00000003 | 00000004 | 00000001 |
| 00000004 | 00000005 | 00000002 |
| 00000005 | 00000006 | 00000003 |
| 00000006 | 00000007 | 00000004 |
| 00000007 | 00000008 | 00000005 |
| 00000008 | 00000009 | 00000006 |
| 00000009 | 00000010 | 00000007 |
| 00000010 |  | 00000008 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a **JavaScript for EmEditor** macro. `MoveCells( -1, true )` copies the selected cells up to right, and `MoveCells( 1, false )` moves the selected cells down.

```
// yShift : Specify how many rows to shift (move) the cell selection ( >0 : down, <0 : up )
function MoveCells( yShift, bCopy )
{
    if( !yShift || yShift == 0 ) {
        Quit();
    }
    if( !document.CellMode ) {   // Must be cell selection mode
        alert( "Cell selection mode must be turned on" );
        Quit();
    }

    xTop = document.selection.GetTopPointX(eePosCellLogical);
    yTop = document.selection.GetTopPointY(eePosCellLogical);
    xBottom = document.selection.GetBottomPointX(eePosCellLogical);
    yBottom = document.selection.GetBottomPointY(eePosCellLogical);

    yLines = document.GetLines();   // retrieve the number of lines
    if( document.GetLine( yLines ).length == 0 ) {  // -1 if the last line is empty
        --yLines;
    }

    if( yTop < 0 || xTop < 0 || xBottom < 0 || yBottom < 0 ) {
        alert( "Incorrect selection" );
        Quit();
    }
    if( xTop != xBottom ) {
        alert( "More than one columns are selected" );
        Quit();
    }

    bOldRedraw = Redraw;
    Redraw = false;
    bOldCombineHistory = CombineHistory;
    CombineHistory = false;
    yFirstLine = document.HeadingLines + 1;
    if( (yShift < 0 && yTop + yShift < yFirstLine) || (yShift > 0 && yBottom + yShift > yLines) ) {
        if( yShift < 0 ) {
            document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, xTop, yFirstLine );  // move to the first line
            nCount = yFirstLine - (yTop + yShift);
            for( i = 0; i < nCount; ++i ) {
                document.selection.LineOpen(true);
            }
            yTop += nCount;
            yBottom += nCount;
        }
        else {
            document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, xTop, yLines );  // move to the first line
            nCount = yBottom + yShift - yLines;
            for( i = 0; i < nCount; ++i ) {
                document.selection.LineOpen(false);
            }
        }
    }

    sDelimiter = document.Csv.Delimiter;  // retrieve the delimiter
    str = document.GetColumn( xTop, sDelimiter, eeCellIncludeQuotes, yTop, yBottom - yTop + 1 );  // get cell selections from top to bottom, separated by delimiter

    if( bCopy ) {
        ++xTop
        document.InsertColumn( xTop );
    }

    if( yShift > 0 ) {  // shift down
        for( i = 0; i < yShift; ++i ) {  // insert delimiters before the copied string
            str = sDelimiter + str;
        }
        document.SetColumn( xTop, str, sDelimiter, eeDontQuote, yTop );
    }
    else {              // shift up
        for( i = 0; i < -yShift; ++i ) {  // add delimiters to the copied string
            str += sDelimiter;
        }
        document.SetColumn( xTop, str, sDelimiter, eeDontQuote, yTop + yShift );
    }

    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, xTop, yTop + yShift );  // move the current selection
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, xTop, yBottom + yShift, true );

    Redraw = bOldRedraw;
    CombineHistory = bOldCombineHistory;
}

// Here is the main code
MoveCells( -1, true );  // Copy the selection up to right
MoveCells( 2, false );  // Move the selection down
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Macro.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Macro.jsee** in the **Macros** menu while the current CSV document is active.

**References:**

- [Macro: GetColumn Method](http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_document_getcolumn.html)
- [Macro: SetColumn Method](http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_document_setcolumn.html)

Comment: Fantasic - speed is excellent on large files. Thanks Yutaka.

Comment: I've updated the code to avoid `Overflow` error when the `MoveCells` function was called without parameters.